# PL SQL String comparison

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm writing a procedure in PL/SQL, where I need to check whether a given value does not equal *x* or *y*. I use the following code to check:

```
IF p_campaignPaymentType != 'per month' || 'per creation' THEN
    RAISE ex_invalidPaymentType;
END IF;
```

Now, even if the string given in p_campaignPaymentType is 'per month' or 'per creation', it raises the exception ex_invalidPaymentType.

What is the problem with the IF-sentence, and/or what could I do to as an alternative for checking?

Comment: `||` is string concatenation operator, not logical `OR` operator (even if it was it'd be used incorrectly anyway). Use `OR` operator.

Comment: @nicholas-krasnov Using `OR` instead of `||` resulted in the following error: Error(53,46): `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`

Comment: First of all, sorry for `OR` operator in the phrase "Use `OR` operator", it was a typo I meant to say `AND`, of course. You need to place it between two logical conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is the string concatination operator, not the logical or operator I think you're assuming it is. So, your snippet actually means:

```
IF p_campaignPaymentType != 'per monthper creation' THEN
    RAISE ex_invalidPaymentType;
END IF;
```

But even if it were the logical `or` operator, it would still be wrong, as any string is either not equal to `'per month'` or to `'per creation'` (e.g., `'per month'` is not equal to `'per creation'`). Instead, you should use the logical `and` operator:

```
IF p_campaignPaymentType != 'per month' AND 
   p_campaignPaymentType != 'per creation' THEN
    RAISE ex_invalidPaymentType;
END IF;
```

Or, more elegantly, the `not in` operator:

```
IF p_campaignPaymentType NOT IN ('per month', 'per creation') THEN
    RAISE ex_invalidPaymentType;
END IF;
```

Comment: Cheers! That solved my problem. I can't accept your answer for another 7 minutes, but I'll make sure to do it :)